# Configure babelrc location for Webpack's babel-loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I want to have multiple babelrc files in my repo and I have multiple Webpack config files. I want to different babelrc files for some Webpack configs. I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          configFile: 'babel.server.js',
        },
      },
    ],
```

Is it possible to set the Babel config file?

Comment: Please be more specific, what doesn't work? Does Babel throw an error?

Comment: It seems to ignore that option, it's the same as not having it, even though it's in the Babel docs

Comment: If it isn't erroring, then it should definitely loading the file. It's a JS file, so if you put a `console.log` in it, does it output the log when you run Webpack? Most likely it is loading, but the question would then be, what's in the file, what do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: @LeoJiang were you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do this same thing. But instead of specifying the path to the config file I was able to just add the configs directly to the webpack loader in the webpack config file. Then delete the babel-loader config file.